# Cannot type switch on non-interface value

Tags: interface, go, type-conversion

I am playing with type assertion using the following dummy code, and I got the error:

> cannot type switch on non-interface value

Does anyone know what does that mean?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}

type Number struct {
    v int
}

func (number *Number) String() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(number.v)
}

func main() {
    n := &Number{1}
    switch v := n.(type) {
    case Stringer:
        fmt.Println("Stringer:", v)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Unknown")
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Ti4FG0m1mc

Comment: but what would be the point of doing type assertion on a known type?

Comment: @newacct Yeah, in production code you certainly don't do type assertion if the type is already known.  The point of this exercise is to understand type assertion.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Type switches require an interface to introspect.  If you are passing a value of known type to it it bombs out.  If you make a function that accepts an interface as a parameter, it will work:

```
func typeSwitch(tst interface{}) {
    switch v := tst.(type) {
        case Stringer:
           fmt.Println("Stringer:", v)
        default:
           fmt.Println("Unknown")
    }
}
```

See the full code here http://play.golang.org/p/QNyf0eG71_ and the golang documentation on interfaces http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, @dethtron5000.  What I was missing is that an explicit cast to `interface{}` is required before the `type assertion`.

Comment: This answer helped me hugely. I'm resolving some more complicated situation with switches of struct types, but this pushed me in wright direction. Thank you man. Loged in just to tell you that)

Comment: This answer helped me hugely. I'm resolving some more complicated situation with switches of struct types, but this pushed me in wright direction. Thank you man. Loged in just to tell you that)

Answer (score 84):

I figured out the answer, which is to cast `n` to `interface{}` before the type assertion:

```
switch v := interface{}(n).(type)
```

Comment: There would be no reason to use this code in real life, since any non-interface variable (ie, `n`) already has a known type in your source code which cannot change.  Eg, if it's declared as an int, you know it's an int anyway.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this has got so many upvotes then? Surely people are finding a use-case

Comment: For some reason I had an array of pointers to structs, and when I manipulated the array (added items), it became not an interface when I went to try to type assert. Casting to interface{} fixed the 'non interface type on left' error.

Comment: My case was parsing a yaml file with maps

Comment: yes so the short answer is that if Go knew the type of the input, that's the wrong input for type casting/assertion. So you must cast the input into an interface{} some how you could do it in an external function or like shown here.

Comment: Thanks! it helped me to avoid creating the typeSwitch func described in other answers. @tomasrutter this also could happen when you work with generics, e.g. func method[T](n T)

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of type conversions

1. conversion between basic data types. For this we can use the direct casting

   i := 48

   str := string(i)
2. But type conversion using value.(type) is for conversion among the class hierarchy, (e.g. where we want to get the specific implementation from the interface). Else, we get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

There are no typecasts in Go. You are doing a type conversion.