# Type switch from superset to subset interface type

Tags: go

I need to store an object that implements a specific type in an in-memory store. The type of the object being stored must satisfy an interface which is a superset of the interface implemented by the stored object.

What I'm trying to figure out is how do I access the original [interface] type when I retrieve the object from the store? The type switch from superset to subset does not seem to be possible.

Here is a sample code that will hopefully make this easier to understand.

Interface types

```
type Object interface {
    UID() string
    Name() string
    Attrs() map[string]string
    Parent() string
}

type Entity interface {
    UID() string
    Name() string
    Attrs() map[string]string
}

type Node interface {
    Entity
}

type SpecialNode interface {
    Node
    ID() int
}
```

You can see that `Object` interface is a subset of `Entity` interface i.e. all `Object`s automatically implement `Entity` interface, hence `Entity` is a superset of `Object`.

Sample implementations of the interfaces:

```
type node struct {
    Node
}

type specialNode struct {
    Node
    id int
}

func (n specialNode) ID() int {
    return n.id
}

type object struct {
    uid    string
    name   string
    attrs  map[string]string
    parent string
}

func (e object) UID() string              { return e.uid }
func (e object) Name() string             { return e.name }
func (e object) Attrs() map[string]string { return e.attrs }
func (e object) Parent() string           { return e.parent }
```

Now, here is a sample `main.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    o := object{
        uid:    "xyz",
        name:   "entName",
        attrs:  make(map[string]string),
        parent: "entParent",
    }

    n := node{
        Node: o,
    }

    sn := specialNode{
        Node: n,
        id:   100,
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", sn)
}
```

This prints the following as expected:

```
main.specialNode{Node:main.node{Node:main.object{uid:"xyz", name:"entName", attrs:map[string]string{}, parent:"entParent"}}, id:100}
```

Now, how do I "extract" `object/Object` from `sn`? Type switching like this `sn.Node.(Object)` is not possible. Is there any way to accomplish this in `Go`?

Link to [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3UpmDLLBw4M)

Comment: What do you mean by extract object/Object fron sn? sn.Node.Node is actually an implementation of Object interface

Comment: I want to retrieve the object from memory, switch type it to `Object` type and use any of `Object` methods. I'm not sure what you mean by `sn.Node.Node`?

Comment: "The type switch from superset to subset does not seem to be possible." All you need is a simple type conversion: https://play.golang.org/p/Rms0yPArDLa

Answer (score -1):

You have to cast it to an interface to type cast

See [Cannot type switch on non-interface value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172219/cannot-type-switch-on-non-interface-value)

```
o2:= interface{}(sn.Node.(node).Entity.(object))
var oo2 Object = o2.(Object)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n",oo2)
```

Comment: there is no need for the `interface{}` type cast. `interface{}` type implements all interfaces. This will do fine: `sn.Node.(node).Entity.(Object)`. If you correct the original answer I'll accept it